# Drawning two data in the pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table

I have machines and the quality and quantity of the goods produced. These are as in my first table example in my query.  I just want to make it like second table. So, the two data (Machines&Qualities) will become headers.  Is this possible?

You can think of the table query in its simple form as follows:

```
select * from Production
```

(I try to ask the job in my hand simple. Do not search logic for this example :) )

[image: TABLES]

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here, please explain the logic you're after here. What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? There are literally 100's of examples of how to "pivot" data in SQL Server on [so]; what were wrong with all those examples? What does *"I try to ask the job in my hand simple. Do not search logic for this example"* mean?

Comment: In the simplest , how can we bring the top query to the bottom query in sql?

Comment: Do you have a fixed list of quality/machine tuples, or it needs to be dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when quality = 1 and machine = 1 then piece end) m1q1,
       sum(case when quality = 1 and machine = 3 then piece end) m3q1,
       sum(case when quality = 2 and machine = 1 then piece end) m1q2,
       sum(case when quality = 2 and machine = 2 then piece end) m2q2
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is the easiest if you can hardcode all the values beforehand.

If you have a dynamic number of machines and/or quality, however, you need a dynamic query that will build a PIVOT table for you.

```sql
DECLARE @sqlStatement nvarchar(max) = ''

-- Build our PIVOT headers dynamically using a matrix of all possible machine & quality combinations
select @sqlStatement =  
    STRING_AGG(concat('[', m.machine, '&', q.quality, ']'), ', ') 
from  (select distinct quality from production) q
full join  (select distinct machine from production) m on 1=1
  
 -- Build our entire PIVOT query using our dynamic headers 
SET @sqlStatement = N'
SELECT * FROM (
    /* this is our query if it were straightforward, in multiple rows */
    select 
        concat(matrix.machine, ''&'', matrix.quality) as header,
        sum(isnull(p.piece, 0)) as total
    from (  
                /* this is our matrix of all possible machine & quality combinations */
                select
                    m.machine,
                    q.quality
                from  (select distinct quality from production) q
                full join (select distinct machine from production) m on 1=1
    ) matrix
    left join production p on matrix.machine = p.machine 
        and matrix.quality = p.quality
    group by concat(matrix.machine, ''&'', matrix.quality)
) a 
PIVOT ( /* pivot the rows into columns */
    SUM(total)
    FOR header
    IN ('+@sqlStatement+') /* use our dynamic headers from earlier */
 ) AS PivotTable
 '
 
 EXEC(@sqlStatement)
```

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/df97d/61/0)